# How to add cells to custom sections in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, uitableview

I have three sections in my `UITableView` and when I create objects to go into this `UITableView`, I want to specify which section I want it to go into. I do this by adding it to one of three arrays. Note all objects are initially added to a holder `NSMutableArray` called objects.

```
for (Profile *p in self.objects) {
        if ([p.type isEqualToString:@"eol"]) {
            [self.eolobjects addObject:p];
        }
        else if ([p.type isEqualToString:@"ae"]) {
            [self.aeobjects addObject:p];
        }
       else if ([p.type isEqualToString:@"mw"]) {
            [self.mwobjects addObject:p];
        }
```

The problem arises when I want to segue to a detailViewController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Profile *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];

    }
}
```

Because of the line:

```
    Profile *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
```

If I click (for example)the first object in any section, I will always create an object of the item at the first index of the objects array, not the object in the first index of the array which populates the section I am clicking in. The same is true if I change `self.objects` to any of my three other arrays.

Is there an easier way to add cells to sections in a `UITableView` or is there a way to fix my problem? Thanks

My data source methods look like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 3;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section ==0) {
        return @"Evolution of Life";
    }
    else if (section==1){
        return @"Active Earth";
    }
    else if (section==2){
        return @"Mineral Wealth";
    }
    return @"";
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    switch (section) {
        case 0: return self.eolobjects.count; break;
        case 1: return self.aeobjects.count; break;
        case 2: return self.mwobjects.count; break;
    }

    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        Profile *profile = self.eolobjects[indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [profile name];
        return cell;
    }

    else if (indexPath.section ==1){
        Profile *profile = self.aeobjects[indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [profile name];
        return cell;
    }

    else if (indexPath.section ==2){
        Profile *profile = self.mwobjects[indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [profile name];
        return cell;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions

- Try this

  ```
  Profile *object =nil;
  switch (indexPath.) {
       case 0: object = self.eolobjects[indexPath.row]; break;
       case 1: object =  self.aeobjects[indexPath.row]; break;
       case 2: object = self.mwobjects[indexPath.row]; break;
  }
  ```
- Or you can put all the 3 arrays in one array and access them easily like this `allObjects[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`